# Event Dispatch Event not Firing on Parent LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am having an issue with my dispatched event firing on my parent component:

**Child JS**

```
@api selectedSurveys

 handleAddSurveyClick() {
    this.showSurveyQuestions = false;
    this.selectedSurveys.push({
      surveyLabel: this.surveyNameLabel,
      surveyId: this.surveyNameValue,
      surveyVersionLabel: this.surveyVersionLabel,
      surveyVersionId: this.surveyVersionValue
    });
    //dispatch selected surveys up to parent
    const selectedSurveyItem = new CustomEvent("selectedSurveys", {
      detail: this.selectedSurveys
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(selectedSurveyItem);
```

**Parent JS**

```
  selectedSurveys(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.selectedSurveyData = event.detail;
    console.log(this.selectedSurveyData);
  }
```

It appears that `selectedSurveys()` is not getting called for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume that your template is incorrect. The event handler should be bound as:

```
<c-child onselected-surveys={selectedSurveys}>
```

This is a rather awkward notation; it is recommended that you do not use capital letters at all in event names for this reason, and to conform with the standards.

> The CustomEvent() constructor has one required parameter, which is a
> string indicating the event type. As a component author, you name the
> event type when you create the event. You can use any string as your
> event type. However, we recommend that you conform with the DOM event
> standard.

> - No uppercase letters
> - No spaces
> - Use underscores to separate words

You should read the full [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch) on events for other rules you should obey to avoid complications.